# does javascript functions are shared across all objects?

Tags: javascript, function

so this is some code

```
ob1 = {
 m: function(){
   alert(this);
   }
}

ob2.m = ob1.m;
```

and that is because i think functions are stored once in memory in this case

Comment: What is your question? What is `ob2`?

Comment: i just want to know if iam thinking right? no further explanation needed

Comment: ob2 is the second object which reference ob1 m method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with that code, both `ob1` and `ob2` have a reference to the **same** function `m`. If you call `ob1.m()`, it will call `m` with `this` referring to `ob1`. If you call `obj2.m()`, it will call `m` with `this` referring to `ob2`. There is only *one* copy of the function, and you have multiple *references* to that function. In JavaScript, functions are real objects, just like any other object. (This is not true of many other programming languages.)

You can also do this:

```
function m() {
}

var ob1 = {m: m};
var ob2 = {m: m};
```

Again they share the function.

Or this:

```
function MyObject() {
}
MyObject.prototype.m = function() {
};

var ob1 = new MyObject();
var ob2 = new MyObject();
```

Again they share the function, because they both receive `MyObject.prototype` as their underlying prototype when they're created via `new MyObject`, and the prototype has a reference to the function.

Similarly (in an ES5-enabled environment):

```
var MyProto = {
    m: function() {
    }
};

var ob1 = Object.create(MyProto);
var ob2 = Object.create(MyProto);
```

The object again end up sharing a prototype, and that prototype has the `m` function.

Comment: so the function gets stored in memory once ?

Comment: @AbdulRaziq: Correct, just like any other object.

Comment: thanks T.J its clear now

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Functions are first class objects. You only ever really interact with references to them.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you just store a Link to the function m in ob2.

To make the function global you need the set the object prototype. I don't recommend it, but this should work:

```
Object.prototype.test=1;
{test} --> 1
```

Comment: `Object.prototype` has nothing whatsoever to do with the question (or indeed with making functions "global").

Answer (score -1):

Yes but you can assign the object like below

```
ob2 = ob1;
```

**Not like** `ob2.m = ob1.m;`

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/87/